# IE10 - Setting specific browser & document modes

Tags: internet-explorer-10

I need to get an old web application to display correctly in IE10. Using the developer tools of IE, the configuration of IE10 Compatibility browser mode & IE5 Quirks document mode, proved to be the best configuration.

Using the pages code-behind to adjust the response header to include the 'X-UA-Compatible' HTTP header when the browser is IE10, the document mode is correctly set to IE5 Quirks mode, but the browser mode is still stuck on IE10.

While the web application is being re-factored to be cross-browser compatible, how can I adjust the modes without requiring the user to set any configuration (compatibility view settings) or using the developer's toolbar.

Comment: This may be related to a problem I'm having. Our ancient web app works fine when you click the IE10 Compatibility View button. When I try setting a 'X-UA-Compatible' header to IE5, the majority of the app also renders fine. I just have one very important page which uses an old Infragistics control, which returns a 500 error.  So, how do I emulate the Compatibiliy View in code?

Comment: I have the same problem. Does anyone know if you can change Browser Mode from the webserver ( html or http headers ? ) - doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I have not found a way to change Browser Mode either.

Comment: If the user were to add the site to the Intranet sites group, and set the option to enable Compatibility mode for those sites, one can ensure the correct browser mode. But I have not yet found a solution that does not involve the user to set a preference.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the doc type to:
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5quirks"/>`
This will render the same way as quirks mode did in older versions of IE.

Comment: I did try that, see the description of question. The meta tag only targets the document mode.