# IE10 document mode at the java side

Tags: java, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

Is there any way of getting to know IE document mode on the java servlet. Apparently, I tried to get browser information using "User-Agent" string, but i am unable to get document mode from this.

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383511/ie10-setting-specific-browser-document-modes

Comment: i need the document mode on the java code side. I do not mean to change the document mode on the browser side

Answer (score 0):

To get the document mode of IE, use below Servlet class.

Code:

public class DocumentModeOfIE extends HttpServlet {

```
private String documentMode;

 public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        documentMode = req.getHeader("X-UA-Compatible");

       out.println(documentMode);
}


public void destroy() {
}
```

}

==============To Set the IE document mode to particular standard mode (i.e IE 7 0r IE8)==============

Code :

Using filter....

Filter Class:

public class UserAgentCompatibleFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

```
private Logger log = Logger.getLogger("UserAgentCompatibleFilter");
private String compatibilityMode;

public void destroy() {
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (compatibilityMode != null) {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        res.addHeader("X-UA-Compatible", compatibilityMode);
    }
    chain.doFilter(req, resp);
}

public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    compatibilityMode = config.getInitParameter("compatibilityMode");
    if (compatibilityMode == null) {
        log.warn("No CompatibilityMode set for UserAgentCompatibleFilter, thus disabling it");
    }
}
```

}

web.xml :

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

```
<!-- filter component start -->

<filter>
    <filter-name>UserAgentCompatibleFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.standardandpoors.ata.web.UserAgentCompatibleFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compatibilityMode</param-name>
        <param-value>IE=8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UserAgentCompatibleFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- filter component end -->
```

I hope this will help u most......